# La parola “approcciabile”. Esiste o no?

Tags: single-words

Mi è capitato di scrivere la parola “approcciabile” e notare che veniva segnalata come errata dal correttore automatico. Una ricerca su qualche dizionario online non porta ad alcun risultato. Il che, di per sé, sembrerebbe attestare la sua inesistenza. D'altronde un controllo sui motori di ricerca rivela un certo uso.

Inoltre ai tempi scolastici, e parliamo di più di dieci anni fa, ricordo che fosse usata con due significati:

1. riferito a persona, usata come somma di avvicinabile e disponibile, ovvero nel senso di persona sentimentalmente disponibile e generalmente amichevole. Es. *Ma Michela è approcciabile? No, sta con X./No, è una (insulto).*
2. riferito a cose, usata per indicare una questione facilmente risolvibile. Es. *L'equazione del compito in classe era approcciabile.*

È chiaro che, se ne ammettiamo l'esistenza, il suo è ristretto ad una popolazione giovanile, ma vorrei sapere se qualcun altro ne può attestare l'uso.

Comment: Se è ammesso un commento scherzoso, a prescindere da ciò che si trova nei dizionari penso che tale parola è così brutta che non *dovrebbe* esistere.

Comment: @Daniel: Come tu stesso hai detto, penso che questo sia un commento e non una risposta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

L’assenza d’una parola da un dizionario non ne decreta l’inesistenza. Il dizionario, anche un dizionario dell’uso, è necessariamente in ritardo rispetto al rapido sviluppo della lingua. Inoltre, i compilatori debbono necessariamente fare un lavoro di selezione della mole di neologismi che ogni anno vengono creati, la maggior parte dei quali è classificabile tra gli occasionalismi.

Ciò detto, bisogna aggiungere che i dizionari in genere non includono tutti i derivati di una parola, in specie se il derivato non assume un significato sostanzialmente diverso da quello della sua base. Per fare un esempio, *arabescatore* con ogni probabilità non è messo a lemma da nessun dizionario; tuttavia, è una parola possibile, e può essere adoperata senza problemi, nonostante l’assenza dai dizionari, nei contesti adeguati.

In breve, ci sono parole escluse dai dizionari ma esistenti in potenza, formate rispettando le regole di derivazione italiane, e perfettamente comprensibili a tutti i parlanti nativi. *Approcciabile* è tra queste: come si dice — in un modo d’esprimersi che ad alcuni può risultare indigeribile — «Approcciare una ragazza» o «Approcciare un compito in classe», cosí si può dire anche «Ragazza *approcciabile*» o «Compito in classe *approcciabile*».

Comment: +1 per "Ragazza approcciabile"

Comment: Sono cosciente della possibilità di derivare nuove parole, ma francamente non mi era mai capitato di vedermi segnalata come errata una parola di questo tipo. Da ciò è nato il mio dubbio. Anche perché un correttore ortografico dovrebbe essere in grado di derivare le parole regolari possibili senza alcun problema.

Comment: @gabriele Ho fatto una verifica in _Pages_ di _Apple_, ma pare che riconosca solo le parole derivate presenti nel dizionario incorporato. _Approcciabile_ me lo sottolinea in rosso, cosí come _arabescatore_. Segna in rosso anche _inconfutabilità_, parola la cui liceità (in testi filosofici ma non solo) credo sia fuor di dubbio.

Comment: “Approcciabile” è proprio indigeribile. `;-)`

Comment: @gabriele: I "correttori ortografici" tipicamente *non* applicano regole di produzione ma si limitano a verificare l'esistenza di un vocabolo in una lista data. Aggiungere al vocabolario del tuo correttore "pirippippare" non risulta in "pirippipai, pirippippasti..."

Comment: @Tobia Tesan, mi sembra più una mancanza che un'impossibilità tecnica, vista l'esistenza di stemmer, anche per l'italiano.

Comment: @gabriele: "*tipicamente*" :)

Comment: @TobiaTesan Non sono un informatico, ma il problema dell’assenza di parole derivate dai correttori automatici non riguarda tanto la sua impossibilità tecnica, che a quanto ho capito non sussiste, ma l’impossibilità d’includere tutti i possibili derivati, anche e soprattutto perché non tutti i derivati, per quanto morfologicamente ineccepibili, sono accolti nell’uso. La lingua non satura tutte le sue valenze, sicché, ad es., _bisognoso_ esiste, ma non *_bisognosità_ (è il cosiddetto blocco morfologico nella formazione delle parole).

Comment: Sviluppo il discorso in un altro commento, perché ho raggiunto il limite di caratteri. Il blocco agisce inibendo l’accoglimento di una parola derivata ben formata perché esiste già un’altra parola col medesimo significato. Cosí *_bisognosità_ non è possibile perché c’è già _bisogno_, e *_rubatore_ non si usa perché esiste già _ladro_.

Comment: There goes "pirippippositá".